# Apache: list of resources to look for when client requests a file

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, directoryindex

Apache's [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive tells Apache to look for, e.g. `index.html` and `index.php` if the client requests a directory.

Is there some easy way to get Apache to analogously look for e.g. `/$filename.jpg` if the client requests `/$filename`?

For example, if the client requested `/foo`, then Apache might be configure to look for `/foo.jpg` and `/foo.png` on disk, and return a 404 if neither of these files exist.  (I am aware that it's possible to use `mod_rewrite` for this, however I would like a simple (and more performant) solution.)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use `Options Multiviews` for this; documentation is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html) for that purpose but you'll run into problems if you have several documents with "similar" names in the document root.

I'd prefer the solution with mod_rewrite over mod_speling.

Answer (score 0):

Do a single redirect non-existing-files to index.php, find the potential files and return it with PHP instead.

Comment: A valid solution, although this is probably much slower than just using mod_rewrite for that purpose. At least with a fixed list of file extensions to check.

Comment: Absolutely, it does however answer the question raised and as far as simple goes, there's likely already code for this exact "issue" on the internet :)